# Aggregate data with custom function

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I have a data.table which looks this:

```
Category   Sub-Category     Status
   A            1            Draft
   A            2            Draft
   A            3            Draft
   A            4            Draft
   A            5            Draft
   A            6            Draft
   B            1            Final
   B            2            Draft
   B            3            Final
   B            4            Final
   C            1            Final
   C            2            Final
   C            3            Final
   C            4            Final
   C            5            Final
```

I want to aggregate this data by Category so that:

1. the status is "Draft" if all the sub-categories are a status of "Draft"
2. the status is "Hybrid" if the sub-categories have status's that are a mix of "Draft" and "Final"
3. the status is "Final" if the all the sub-categories are a status of "Final"

The final output will look like this:

```
Category   Status
   A       Draft
   B       Hybrid
   C       Final
```

I know that if the function I was applying was sum, I could do something like this:

```
df <- aggregate(Status ~ Category, data = df, sum)
```

The issue for me is that this would require a custom function of some sort

Comment: So why can't you write a custom function and then apply it just like you do with `sum`? It should take no longer than 2-3 minutes to write it as your logic is very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, try this..

```
customFunc <- function(x){

    if (length(unique(as.character(x))) == 2){
        return('Hybrid')
    }

    else {
        return(unique(as.character(x)))
    }

}

df <- aggregate(Status ~ Category, data = df, customFunc)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Also the printing the number of unique is a very elegant solution.